# How do I call Pay U Money Server through WCF?

Tags: wcf, payumoney

i am creating a wcf service for Pay u Money I wrote same code like asp.net c# for Pay u Money, but using HttpWebRequest I'm facing this error:

> SORRY! We were unable to process your payment

Same code I tried in simple asp.net c# and there working fine. Here I don't know what goes wrong, how could I solve this?

```
enter code here

      public PayUMoneyModel PayUMoney(PayUMoneyModel Data)
    {
        PayUMoneyModel objPayUMoneyModel = new PayUMoneyModel();
        action1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYU_BASE_URL"] + 
        "/_payment";
        try
        {

            string[] hashVarsSeq;
            string hash_string = string.Empty;


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data.txnid)) // generating txnid
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                string strHash = Generatehash512(rnd.ToString() + 
                 DateTime.Now);
                txnid1 = strHash.ToString().Substring(0, 20);

            }
            else if(Data.txnid!=null)
            {
                txnid1 = Data.txnid;
            }


               Data.txnid = txnid1;
                Data.key= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MERCHANT_KEY"];
                string salt= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SALT"];
            System.Collections.Hashtable data = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

            data.Add("key", Data.key);
            data.Add("txnid", Data.txnid);

           string AmountForm = Convert.ToDecimal(Data.amount).ToString("g29");// eliminating trailing zeros

            //amount.Text = AmountForm;

            data.Add("amount", 1.00);
            data.Add("firstname", Data.firstname);
            data.Add("email", Data.email);
            data.Add("phone", Data.phone);
            data.Add("productinfo", Data.productinfo);
            data.Add("surl", Data.surl);
            data.Add("furl", Data.furl);
            data.Add("lastname", Data.lastname);
            data.Add("curl", Data.curl);
            data.Add("address1", Data.address1);
            data.Add("address2", Data.address2);
            data.Add("city", Data.city);
            data.Add("state", Data.state);
            data.Add("country",Data.country);
            data.Add("zipcode", Data.zipcode);
            data.Add("udf1", Data.udf1);
            data.Add("udf2", Data.udf2);
            data.Add("udf3", Data.udf3);
            data.Add("udf4", Data.udf4);
            data.Add("udf5", Data.udf5);
            data.Add("pg", Data.pg);

            data.Add("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
     hash_string = Data.key + "|" + Data.txnid + "|" + AmountForm + "|" + Data.productinfo+ "|" + Data.firstname + "|" + Data.email + "|||||||||||" + salt;
              string hash = Generatehash512(hash_string);
            data.Add("hash", hash);
            data.Add("abc", hash_string);
            string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(action1, data);

            if (strForm != "")
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action1);
               // httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
               httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = strForm.Length;
                string Json = "";
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(strForm,0,strForm.Length);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        Json = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Replace(";", "");
                    }
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Json);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return objPayUMoneyModel;
    }
```

this is my Post Form Method

```
      private string PreparePOSTForm(string url, System.Collections.Hashtable data)      // post form
    {
        //Set a name for the form
        string formID = "PostForm";
        //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
        strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" +
                       formID + "\" action=\"" + url +
                       "\" method=\"POST\">");

        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry key in data)
        {

            strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key.Key +
                           "\" value=\"" + key.Value + "\">");
        }


        strForm.Append("</form>");
        //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." +
                         formID + ";");
        strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");
        //Return the form and the script concatenated.
        //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
        return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
    }
```

this is my key and salt provided by Payumoney website:-
Key:-rjQUPktU
Salt:-e5iIg1jwi8

Comment: I am not familiar with Payumoney, but in general it is not advisable to publish your key to the web, since it would allow someone to impersonate you or steal the contents of your wallet. Do you need now to revoke that key?

Comment: its a test server key....anyone can use it